# Search button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field on my results page. I used the following event:

```
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('results-search').click()}"
```

The problem is that when I perform a search, nothing happens when I click the search button. It does not work when I click or press enter neither. This occurs only on Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge, but works fine on Google Chrome. Please help

Comment: Why `.click()` ? Invoke the click handler instead...

Comment: Note that results displays on the same page and that everything works well on chrome except on edge and firefox

Comment: Please don't in-line JS, terrible practice. Also if you're using JQuery, why not use `$('#results-search')` as your selector. Seems a bit pointless to load it and not use it.

Answer (score 1):

`event.keyCode` property may not be supported in some browsers. Try to use `event.keyCode || event.which` instead:

```
onkeypress="if ((event.keyCode || event.which) == 13) {document.getElementById('results-search').click()}"
```

If you use `jQuery` it doesn't matter if you use `keyCode` or `which` property, both of them will work. You added `jquery` tag, but you didn't use it in your code.

BTW. isn't it better to handle button's `click` event as well? In my opinion it would look more elegant. It's also good to separate JavaScript code from HTML.

```
document.getElementById('input-search').onkeypress = function(e) 
{ 
    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) === 13) 
        search(); 
};

document.getElementById('results-search').onclick = search;

function search() 
{ 
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I've tried it but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you please suggest another alternative? Thanks

Comment: Did you change input's id to id which you're using? `input-search` was only example. Does console show any error? It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing whole code.